# How to use ImageLoad using Android Universal Image Loader

Tags: java, android, android-listview

On the topic of my previous [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785197/how-to-load-image-after-urlencode-proccess) I have managed to display the image in my listview. It turned out to not be using async in the process of displaying images, I felt heavy listview. I then tried to use the library [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). In my library usage is still a little confused trying to combine and replace the previous use ImageLoader library I use.

I put in `onCreate` in my Activity and my adapter :

```
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(this.getApplicationContext());
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this.getApplicationContext())
            .memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800) // default = device screen dimensions
            .discCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, null)
            .threadPoolSize(3) // default
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1) // default
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
            .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
            .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
            .memoryCacheSizePercentage(13) // default
            .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // default
            .discCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
            .discCacheFileCount(100)
            .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(this.getApplicationContext())) // default
            .build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

In my loop (in `onPostExecute`) :

```
for (int i = 0; i < allData.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject c = allData.getJSONObject(i);

    // Storing each json item in variable
    String id = c.getString(Constants.TAG_MenuID);
    String title = c.getString(Constants.TAG_Title);
    String post = c.getString(Constants.TAG_Post);
    String image = c.getString(Constants.TAG_Image);

    BeritaBean mb = new BeritaBean();
    mb.setID(id);
    mb.setTitle(title);
    mb.setPost(post);
    mb.setImg(image);

    AmbilDataBean.add(mb);
}
adapter.setItem(AmbilDataBean);
```

Then I did also change my adapter of **previous** (using `ImageLoader` class) :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        ImageView img       = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView judul      = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.judul);
        TextView tanggal    = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tanggal);
        TextView isi        = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.isi);

        BeritaBean obj      = (BeritaBean) getItem(position);

        judul.setText(obj.getTitle());
        tanggal.setText(obj.getCreated());
        isi.setText(obj.getPost());

        try {
            String urlImage = obj.getImg();
            if(urlImage.length() > 0){
                img.setTag(urlImage);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(urlImage, img);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return v;
    }
```

Became (using `Universal Image Loader`) on part :

```
try {
        String urlImage = obj.getImg();
        if(urlImage.length() > 0){
            img.setTag(urlImage);
            imageLoader.displayImage(urlImage, img);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

But after my app run turns still images can not be displayed. Is there a setting that is lacking in this library? Please help

Answer (score 1):

that seems a little bit like overkill - for a great library that uses async loading and handles listviews really well, check out koush's (well known dev) [UrlImageViewHelper lib on github](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper)

Comment: It's a very useful and easy to follow